# SVG <text> element inside <a> element no underline in IE

Tags: html, css, svg

Please check this plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/jqPx9qpN3W1Jrix2axPw?p=preview

```
<div width="100px">
  <svg width="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <a xlink:href="#" class="node">
          <text transform="translate(50 50)">hh2</text>
      </a>
  </svg>
</div>

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

On chrome you will see an underline on hover, but on IE there is no underline. I tried solving with css without success.

Comment: "solving using CSS" means exactly what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SVG `text-underline` behaves a little differently than in HTML.

In SVG, [the specification states that it shouldn't inherit.](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#text-TextDecorationProperty)

It appears Chrome and FF have relaxed that restriction.

To get around this in IE, just alter the CSS rule to include the text element.

```css
a:focus text, a:hover text {
    color: #23527c;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div width="100px">
      <svg width="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <a xlink:href="#" class="node">
              <text transform="translate(50 50)">hh2</text>
          </a>
      </svg>
    </div>
```